# syntax error near "," while compiling select

Tags: android

Anyone con find the error in these query?

```
String[] column = {"titolo","regista","cast","descrizione"};
String selection = "_id_film = ? ";
String[] selection_args = {Integer.toString(selectedfilm+1)};
Cursor cursor = db.query("T_FILM", column, selection,selection_args, null, null, null);
```

logcat says:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: syntax error near"," (code 1) :, while compling SELECT titolo,regista,cast,descrizione FROM T_FILM WHERE _id_film=?
```

Comment: The answer below explains it, especially tricky considering english is not your native tongue, italian naming for columns clashing with reserved Sqlite keywords without you realizing it.

Answer (score 2):

"Cast" is a reserved operation in SQLLite. So it's trying to interpret the column name "cast" as an operation. Your easiest answer is to change the column name to something else.

Comment: Good catch, and spot on! Very difficult to spot the error. That explains it.